# VueJS with Materialize and jQuery

Tags: jquery, vuejs2, materialize

I'm used `vue init webpack` to generate my project and `npm install jquery` and `npm install materialize-css` to install the dependencies,  but I'm have an error.

I'm trying to use materialize [modal javascript](http://materializecss.com/modals.html)

this is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:977), <anonymous>:7595:11)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:977), <anonymous>:8269:2)
at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:977)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:660)
at fn (app.js:86)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:772), <anonymous>:6:74)
at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:772)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:660)
at fn (app.js:86)
at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:958)
```

this is the `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import Materialize from 'materialize-css'
import jQuery from 'jquery'

Vue.use(Materialize)
Vue.use(jQuery)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

this is my vue file

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn-link v-modal:modal>Modal</v-btn-link>
    <v-modal id="modal">
      <div slot="content">
        <h4>Modal Header</h4>
        <p>A bunch of text</p>
      </div>
      <div slot="footer">
        <v-btn-link class="pull-right" waves-light modal flat>Disagree</v-btn-link>
        <v-btn-link class="pull-right" waves-light modal flat>Agree</v-btn-link>
      </div>
    </v-modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
  }
</script>
```

This project is just a test, because I'm learning VueJS.

Does anyone know how can I fix this?

Comment: Try this in the main.js file: `import {$, jQuery} from 'jquery'`.

Comment: you are importing jquery with the jQuery  namespace you need the $ namespace see ba_ul comment

Comment: I'm not the world expert, but why do you want vue **and** jquery. I'm not aware of folks using vue who find useful (or miss) jquery.